# Why isn't SharePointPlus sending image from Airwatch browser on iPad?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ipad, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I am creating a form on an html page and I am having trouble posting a picture to a SharePoint document folder, the method that I am using works perfect in Google Chrome on desktop and successfully posts to the SharePoint folder but doesn't want to work on AirWatch browser on an iPad for some reason and I can't find any good documentation on Airwatch. I am using SharePointPlus javascript library to push the image to SharePoint. The image is successfully converted to base64 and I can print the base64 string into a textbox on the html page.

When I am on the iPad/Airwatch, i choose the picture, and the base64 string is pasted into a textbox, then I click the Send Data button and I don't receive the after:function alert I have set and the picture doesn't post to SharePoint. The SharePointPlus documentation is pretty sparse as well.

Here is my SharePointPlus createFile function in javascript that is triggered when I click submit:

```
var fileName;

function changeHandler(inputElement){
   var fileReader, file;
   fileReader=new FileReader();
   var fileList=inputElement.files;
   file=fileList[0];
   // console.log(file.name);
   fileName = file.name;
   fileReader.onload=load_handler;
   fileReader.readAsDataURL(file);
}

function load_handler(event){
   var url=event.target.result;
   // removes data:image/jpeg:base64 from beginning of base64
   url = url.substring(url.indexOf(',')+1);
   // console.log(url);
   fileInBase64 = url;
   document.getElementById("log").value=fileInBase64;
}//end function load_handler


$("#submit_pic").click(function(){
    //fileName is the base64 encoded image string
    myImage = fileInBase64;

    $SP().createFile({
        content:myImage,
        encoded:true,
        destination:"http://example.com/folder/Code/myfile.jpg",
        url:"/folder",
        after:function(){alert('done');}
     });
  });
```

Edit: Now I think it has something to do with the base64 string on the iPad, after inspecting the string and trying to convert it back to an image via a website it doesn't work right... here is all the code that grabs the file, converts to base64, and tries to submit it.

If I alert myImage, I get a very large alert box that is spanning the height of the iPad with no text in it. So it looks like there is something there, but not really. If i alert a hardcoded string it looks fine.

Technologies used:
SharePoint 2010
Jquery
SPServices
SharePointPlus
AirWatch browser w/Ipad
Chrome on Desktop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that the image size is to large. If I take a picture with the iPad that's zoomed in I am able to upload the picture just fine. It has to be about half way zoomed in. Not sure how else to go about this but it'll work for now.